# How to calculate ratio between numbers in a vector?

Tags: arrays, julia

If I have a vector:

```
x = [1,2,6,3]
```

And I want to calculate the ratio of the numbers, what's an easy way to do this?

E.g. I want:

```
[2.0,3.0,0.5]
```

Comment: just use a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either write a loop,

```
[x[i+1] / x[i] for i = 1:length(x)-1]
```

or use a vectorized division:

```
@views x[2:end] ./ x[1:end-1]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 3.0
 0.5
```

In terms of performance, both would be identical. The vectorized form, however, might be the preferred approach for more generic (think GPU) and arguably more readable code.

Comment: If genericity is important: `x[begin+1:end] ./ x[begin:end-1]`